# Get location (path) of the shorctut calling a batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have an ongoing list of 'Enquiry' folders within a directory.  I'm trying to create a batch file that can sit within each of these folders that, when run, will move the folder it resides in to a 'Projects' folder.

From my attempts, and as half expected, I'm realising it's not possible to move the folder containing the batch file (or copy folder and then delete source folder containing the batch), so my second thought is to position a single 'master' batch file outside of the 'Enquiry' folders, and have a shortcut within each Enquiry folder that links to that 'external' batch file.

For this, I'd need to obtain the location path of the shortcut calling the batch, is this possible?

Or is there a better way to achieve my aim?

Comment: Can't you just have a batch file with the same name as the folder and then just add a ".cmd" extension to the folder's name to get the batch file name?

Comment: Hi Klitos, thanks for your reply.  I'm afraid I don't get what you're saying (I am a newbie at batch stuff, and a novice coder in general!).  All Enquiry folders are created by copying a template folder and renaming, so I'm after something that can go in that template folder and do the job without additional input.

Comment: Let's assume you currently have a main folder called C:\main. Inside this folder, you have subfolders called "enquiry1" and "enquiry2". Inside folder "enquiry1" you have a batch file called "process.cmd". Inside folder "enquiry2" you have a batch file also called "process.cmd". That's how I understood your current setup.  What I'm saying is that you shouldn't have the batch files inside the folders "enquiry1" and "enquiry2". Instead, have batch files inside "C:\main" called "enquiry1.cmd" and "enquiry2.cmd". Then when you look at each folder, just add ".cmd" to get the batch file name.

Comment: Klitos, the penny has dropped with what you're saying.  I think I should clarify how I intend it working.  The idea is a user opens folder  'Enquiry1' folder and the double clicks on a batch file (or shortcut to one) wthin it that is called 'Make Project', which then moves 'Enquiry1' into the 'PROJECTS' folder (it will also rename 'Enquiry1' to have the next project number, but that bit has already been taken care of with help from others here).

Comment: My comment above  crossed over with your previous response.  I understand what your saying, but I'd like the batch file within the enquiry as it means the batch file automatically exists from the template folder.  I think using [this](http://www.marijn.org/archive/batch-files-variables/) might be the answer.

Comment: I understand now. Unfortunately, there's no built-in way to handle shortcuts outside of Windows Explorer (which means the shortcuts have to be created manually). There are some third-party utilities that can deal with shortcuts but I haven't tried them. One possible solution is to have a batch file in the enquiry folder (which the user clicks on) which then transfers control to another batch file outside of the folder (it can pass command-line parameters, such as the folder name, to the master batch file). It should transfer control to the master batch file, i.e. don't use CALL.

Comment: Thanks Klitos.  I used the approach I linked to with success up to a point - I can copy and delete the contents of the Enquiry1 folder, but the Enquiry1 folder itself does not delete, and I get the error 'The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process' - presumably because the folder is still displayed in explorer as that's where everything started from. My initial research suggests it's not possible to make a batch file close the window, any ideas/workarounds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following on from the comments to your question, the reason it doesn't move the folder is that when the batch file runs, the current directory is still the enquiry folder. You need to move out of it and then move it. Also, as it turns out, you don't have to delegate to a "master" batch file either. You can just do the move in the same batch file (but the move should be the last line of the batch file; once the batch file itself moves, the command processor won't be able to read the following lines).

```
setlocal
set enqfolder=%cd%
cd ..
move %enqfolder% ..\projects
```

Comment: Thankyou so much Klitos!  Your method is so much simpler than the path I was going down, and the 'cd ..' solves the issue too.  Brilliant, really appreciate your help, thanks again.

Comment: Comment removed and re-added as answer for correct formatting.

Answer (score 1):

Just an extra note in case it helps anyone, I had to make the following changes to ensure file path with space was ok (putting %enqfolder% in quotes) and I also need to a '\' after 'projects' in the move command.  Thanks again to @Klitos.

```
setlocal
set enqfolder=%cd%
cd ..
move "%enqfolder%" ..\projects\
```